# Excel SUMIFS question: multiple criteria’s with AND?

Tags: excel, sumifs

Novice Excel user here. I am trying to figure out to solve a bit of an Excel SUMIFS pickle. I am trying to total all the revenue of 8 cost centres from a particular revenue account with a particular description. The data has multiple cost-centres from different divisions, so that revenue would not assist with my reconciliation process.

So my question is, is there a way to add multiple criteria in one of the criteria boxes for example cost centre 2965 AND 1955 AND 2344 AND 3966 AND.... instead of doing it the way I have done below, which is so big and confusing:

“ =-SUMIFS($L:$L,$C:$C,Q11,$B:$B,$Y$6,$E:$E,"*Fleet Distribution Revenue*")+-SUMIFS($L:$L,$C:$C,Q11,$B:$B,$Y$7,$E:$E,"*Fleet Distribution Revenue*")+-SUMIFS($L:$L,$C:$C,Q11,$B:$B,$Y$8,$E:$E,"*Fleet Distribution Revenue*")+-SUMIFS($L:$L,$C:$C,Q11,$B:$B,$Y$9,$E:$E,"*Fleet Distribution Revenue*")+-SUMIFS($L:$L,$C:$C,Q11,$B:$B,$Y$10,$E:$E,"*Fleet Distribution Revenue*")+-SUMIFS($L:$L,$C:$C,Q11,$B:$B,$Y$11,$E:$E,"*Fleet Distribution Revenue*")+-SUMIFS($L:$L,$C:$C,Q11,$B:$B,$Y$12,$E:$E,"*Fleet Distribution Revenue*")+-SUMIFS($L:$L,$C:$C,Q11,$B:$B,$Y$13,$E:$E,"*Fleet Distribution Revenue*")”

The Cell Y is the reference to each of the eight cost centres, so I have to do the SUMIF 8 times, which is ridiculous. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

With classical Sumifs, you are using the correct approach.

If you have Office 365, you can use the new Filter() function, to filter the data with different criteria. AND logic is done with a `*` and OR logic is done with a `+` sign.

What you describe as "AND" is really "OR" logic, since a cell can only have one value.

Here is a simplified scenario:

```
=SUM(FILTER(A:A,((B:B=E2)+(B:B=E3)+(B:B=E4)+(B:B=E5)+(B:B=E6))*(C:C="x")))
```

In words: Sum all values from column A where column B is equal to either E2 OR E3 OR E4 OR E5 OR E6 and where column C is equal to x

[image]

Comment: if that resolves your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]